# Wait for all child processes to finish

Tags: powershell, start-process

Currently I am trying to run a script multiple times and let the parent wait for all the child processes to finish.

The creation of the children is as follows:

```
# Spawn balance load processes
$command = "-i $ScriptPath\balanceLoaders\%BALANCE_DIR% -o $outputDirectory -c %BALANCE_DIR%"
#$command = "$ScriptPath\convertFiles.ps1 -i $ScriptPath\balanceLoaders\%BALANCE_DIR% -o $outputDirectory -c %BALANCE_DIR%"
for ([int]$i = 0; $i -lt $b; $i++) {
    #$proc = Start-Process powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Argument $command.Replace('%BALANCE_DIR%', $i) -PassThru
    $proc = Start-Process $ScriptPath\convertfiles.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $command.Replace('%BALANCE_DIR%', $i) -PassThru
}
```

The children are spawned dynamically. Currently I can only track the last spawned child with `$proc`. However, I want to track them all.

Currently using `$proc.WaitForExit()` to wait for the child.

Answer (score 3):

Collect all processes in an array and run an idle loop until all of them have exited.

```
$proc = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $b; $i++) {
    Start-Process ... -PassThru
}

while (($proc | Select-Object -Expand HasExited) -contains $false) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can simplify the loop to something like this:

```
while ($proc.HasExited -contains $false) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```

because PowerShell v3 introduced a new feature called [member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) that allows accessing properties or methods of array elements via the array object.

Comment: Didnt know I could loop inside a variable, nice one!

Comment: And how to get the exit status of each start-process within the while loop. Lets say I want to monitor if a child process doesnt run longer then 5 minutes, how can I check this within the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

[Ansgar Wiecher's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905837/45375) contains good pointers and a working solution, but **if you simply want to wait for *all* spawned processes to terminate, use of `Wait-Process` is simpler**.

That said, **if you want to check exit codes *as they become available***, before *all* processes have exited, **a loop that sleeps periodically (`Start-Sleep`), as in Ansgar's answer, is necessary**.

The following solution demonstrates the **synchronously-wait-for-all technique with `Wait-Process`** with a simplified example that creates 3 instances of Notepad and waits for all of them to terminate:

```
# Create all processes and store objects representing them in array $procs.
$b = 3 # number of processes to create
$procs = foreach ($i in 0..($b-1)) { Start-Process -PassThru Notepad }

# Wait for all processes to exit.
# (Close the Notepad windows manually or, if no Notepad windows were previously
# open, use `Stop-Process -Name Notepad` from another session to forcefully close them.)
# Use Wait-Process -Timeout <secs> to limit the max. period of time to wait.
$procs | Wait-Process 

# Get the exit codes.
$exitCodes = $procs.ExitCode # PSv3+; v2: $procs | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExitCode
```

Or, as a single pipeline:

```
# Use $_ inside { ... } to refer to the current iteration value.
# Use $procs.ExitCode to get the exit codes.
0..($b-1) | ForEach-Object -ov procs { Start-Process -PassThru Notepad } | Wait-Process
```

Note the use of `-ov` - short for common parameter `-OutVariable`, which collects the process objects output by the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet's script block invocations.